# Using BSUB to Submit Bash Scripts to Cluster

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I use a cluster to process scripts I have written and submit these using code like:

```
bsub -n 10 < run.sh
```

The beginning of submitted scripts usually look like:

```
#BSUB -J align[1-10]
#BSUB -e logs/run.%I.%J.err
#BSUB -o logs/run.%I.%J.out
#BSUB -R "span[hosts=1]"
#BSUB -n 10
```

My question is will my scripts use all processors reserved even if the code is not broken up somehow? So if I have something really simple like:

```
echo "this"
```

which does not have multiple files to act on, will it still use multiple processors to compute or just one processor? And if it does use just a single processor, how do I make the script use multiple?

Comment: No, the queuing system isn't going to magically parallelise your single-threaded code for you. If you reserve 10 nodes and only use one, then you're just preventing other people from accessing those nodes unnecessarily. However, you can submit a batch of scripts together in one go - take a look at this [guide to job arrays](http://www.ccs.miami.edu/hpc/lsf/7.0.6/admin/jobarrays.html).

Comment: Tthats what I figured. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would answer this in case anybody was looking for a simple explanation.

```
  #BSUB -J array[1-3]

  #This creates a named array whose size matches that of the array created
  #on the first line
  files=(first.txt second.txt third.txt)

  #This refers to the 0, 1, or 2 item in the files array and sets as the
  #current file
  currentfile=${files[$(($LSB_JOBINDEX - 1))]}

  count = 0

  #Executes some code on each file individually
  while true
      do echo $count >> /dir/${currentfile}
          let "count+=1"
      done
```